# Sort List based on Array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a custom list based on a string array, but I am failing miserably e.g. its not sorting the list at all,

```
Public class CrateOrder
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Stream OrderStream { get; set; }
}

string[] selectedFruits = {"Apple", "Mango"};  // in real get from web services
var selectedFruitsList = selectedFruits.ToList();

List<CrateOrder> cFruit = GetCrateOrderFromWebServices();

var sorted = cFruit.OrderBy(s => selectedFruitsList.IndexOf(s.Name)).ToList();
```

It's not sorting the list properly, I want CrateOrder list item to be ordered based on selectedFruits...

Comment: I still don't understand how you are trying to sort your `cFruit` with your `selectedFruits`.  An input and expected output for `cFruit` would help.

Comment: @ryanyuyu it was a wild guess

Comment: This looks fine to me - maybe I'm just missing the same thing, but are you sure your cFruit list items actually have Name properties that match your selectedFruits?

Comment: That's not a duplicate, there's something else going on here.

Comment: I suspect this is a case-sensitivity issue, `IndexOf` will do a case-sensitive search by default, unless specifying a different rule.

Comment: works for me ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/H1dt6p

Comment: What inputs do you have, what output are you expecting and what are you getting?  Your sort looks fine other than items not in the list will be at the beginning.

Comment: @DStanley I wasn't aware if its case sensitive, can i add ignore culture to it

Comment: @Jamiec Looks like it; using Rhumburl's [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H1dt6p) version but changing the capital letter on the names results in the behaviour the question describes.

Comment: @anaximander indeed, have updated to show this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Name` property of your fruit does not match your ordering list exactly, `IndexOf` will always return -1. To get around this specify a case-insensitive `StringComparison`, but that is not available as an overload to `IndexOf` so you have to use a slightly more complex method:

```
var sorted = cFruit.OrderBy(
                     s => selectedFruitsList.FindIndex(
                            x => x.Equals(s.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) )
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: it worked with some adjustments, e.g. OrderByDescending and converting s.Name tolower, i know it shouldn't matter but thats how it worked, thanks

Comment: The `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` was specifically to *not* have to do any case conversion.

Comment: I know, but for some reason, it wasn't working for me, I will look into it later, too occupied at this time :(

Comment: Here you go: http://rextester.com/ZOIS35246 - works absolutely fine with no need to change the case of anything (Note the Names have some lowercase starting letters)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The code orders the fruit from `selectedFruitsList` *after* all other items, because `OrderBy` order is ascending, and they are the only ones for which a non-negative number is returned.

To fix this, reverse `selectedFruits`, and negate the result of `IndexOf`, like this:

```
string[] selectedFruits = {"Mango", "Apple"};
...
var sorted = cFruit.OrderBy(s => -selectedFruitsList.IndexOf(s.Name)).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could expand the code to deal with negative indexes explicitly:

```
string[] selectedFruits = {"Apple", "Mango"};
...
var sorted = cFruit.OrderBy(s => {
    int index = selectedFruitsList.IndexOf(s.Name);
    return index < 0 ? int.MaxValue : index;
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wasn't aware if its case sensitive, can i add ignore culture to it

No - `Array.IndexOf` does not have parameters that let you customize the equality comparison.

Just change all of your `selectedfruits` and the search value to lower case:

```
string[] selectedFruits = {"Apple", "Mango"};  // in real get from web services
var selectedFruitsList = selectedFruits.Select(s => s.ToUpperInvariant()).ToList();

List<CrateOrder> cFruit = GetCrateOrderFromWebServices();

var sorted = cFruit.OrderBy(s => selectedFruitsList.IndexOf(s.Name.ToUpperInvariant())).ToList;
```

Comment: You should at very least be using `ToLowerInvariant`, but the [recommendation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is "Use the String.ToUpperInvariant method instead of the String.ToLowerInvariant method when you normalize strings for comparison"

Comment: @Jamiec fair enough - modified.